# TypeScript import paths

Tags: typescript, grafana

I am building a grafana plugin using TypeScript, same as [here](https://github.com/grafana/typescript-template-datasource).

The folder structure looks like:
[image]

Unsurprisingly I cannot compile my TypeScript plugin because in `module.ts`

`import { MetricsPanelCtrl } from 'app/plugins/sdk';`

All the examples use the path 'app/plugins/sdk' even though app is nowhere near them in the directory structure.

So how do they do it?

I tried changing my import path to `'../../../../public/app/plugins/sdk'` and that gets further, but then get 1000s of erros about the other modules not compiling like:

```
Running "typescript:build" (typescript) task
>> ../../../public/app/core/components/code_editor/code_editor.ts(30,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/core/config'.
>> ../../../public/app/core/components/code_editor/code_editor.ts(31,17): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'brace'.
```

Comment: normally the public folder is the 'root' for all the files served up to the browser, in a case like this. Are you sure you are serving files outside 'public' ? But relative to your plugin the 'public' folder is "../../../public". But again i don't think you want to keep your plugin where you have it. Your server will not be serving files from there most likely.

Comment: I hear you, will try alongside the installed ones, its just he docs (http://docs.grafana.org/plugins/developing/development/) explicitly say to put it in the data folder

Comment: same issue alongside installed ones..

Comment: found issue, added answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Missed the bottom of the README:

> The Grafana SDK Mocks package contains mocks for the Grafana classes that a plugin needs to build in TypeScript...
>
> npm install --save-dev grafana/grafana-sdk-mocks
>
> Place the directive at the top of all your TypeScript files:
>
> `///<reference path="../node_modules/grafana-sdk-mocks/app/headers/common.d.ts" />`

Comment: That should be avoided. Use the `"files"` property in `tsconfig.json` to reference it if you must.

Comment: @AluanHaddad is correct. You don't want to try to reference node_modules in that way. Check out my project here:
https://github.com/Clay-Ferguson/meta64
and you will find an example of how to pull in ReactJS as an external dependency and you probably need to do something like that. Follow that example. If i can state it humbly,... I know i"m doing it right. :)